# How to change Image based on my specific time iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I have created a movie with images array and saved that to my photo library.

When I play the movie all my images are coming at a time that means if saved 10 images in my movie, when I start playing the movie all my 10 images are appear in single second but the song is goes on playing.

Here my problem is I want to slide my images like:

for first 3 seconds 1st image, next 3 second 2 images like

How to create movie of that type using AVMutableCompositionTrack or something else.

my sample code is:

```
 CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;

AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];
CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);
AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
//NSArray *myarray1 = [videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] ;
[a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

//nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, a_timeRange.duration);

AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];
```